# how to find cosective repeats in a DNA sequence using python?

Tags: python

I have DNA sequence like

```
seq='ATCGTTTTTCGAAACTGCCCCCCACTGGGGA'
```

I want to print consective repeat nucleotides(if it consectively repeat more han two times) in python.

For this sequence output should be

```
TTTTT
AAA
CCCCCC
GGGG
```

Comment: Take a shot, and tell us what you've got.

Comment: I'm not sure why people are marking this question as "not a real question". Its clear, provides an example and what is expected.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to take a look at [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).

An example usage:

```
for _, group in itertools.groupby(seq):
    group = ''.join(group)
    if len(group) > 2:
        print group
```

Comment: +1: [groupby can handle multi GB sequences](http://ideone.com/piXOyK)

Answer (score 1):

You can find the repeats fairly easily with a back referencing [`regular expression`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) and the `findall` method;

```
seq = 'ATCGTTTTTCGAAACTGCCCCCCACTGGGGA'

import re
hits = re.findall(r'(([A-Z])\2\2+)', seq) # regex matching all repeating A-Z groups
print [hit[0] for hit in hits]          # Comprehension to filter the results

['TTTTT', 'AAA', 'CCCCCC', 'GGGG']
```

Comment: it should be `r'([ATCG])\1\1+'` i.e., *more than 2 times*

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Ah, yes, I missed the _more_ than two times, will fix the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
seq='ATCGTTTTTCGAAACTGCCCCCCACTGGGGA'
while len(seq) > 1:
    value = seq[0]
    repeats = 1
    idx = 1
    while 1:
        if seq[idx] == value:
            repeats += 1
        else:
            if repeats > 1: print value*repeats
            seq = seq[repeats:]
            break
        idx += 1
```